# Predicting the sentiment of the constituent phrases from the sentiment of the sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

For those who are not aware of the Stanford sentiment analyzer, their model predicts the sentiment of the sentence using the sentiment scores of various phrases embedded in the sentence. For e.g:
 
**This movie doesn't care about cleverness, wit or any other kind of intelligent humor.**

It has a negative sentiment which it captures using sentiment of various words like :
doesn't, care, witty etc.
It's a bottom up approach where each word has an assigned sentiment, and then the collection of words has a sentiment and so on.
What I need is a reverse process, where the sentiment has been assigned to the sentence and I want to correctly assign the sentiment to the bottom nodes which will lead to this sentiment.
 I am unable to think of a method to do so.